# How to include global library in C++ class?

Tags: c++, class, include

I have the main.cpp, a class Student and a global.h library.

I want the functions of global.h to be acessible everywhere, so I did this.

**global.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

int min(vector<int> v) {
    int min = -99999999;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] > min) min = v[i];
    }
    return min;
}

double average(vector<int> v) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return (double)sum / v.size();
}

#endif  /* GLOBAL_H */
```

**Student.h**

```
#include "global.h"

#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Student {

private:
    string name;
    vector<int> grades;
public:
    Student();
    void setName(string name);
    void addGrade(int grade);
    int getBestGrade();
    double getAverageGrade();
};

#endif  /* STUDENT_H */
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include "Student.h"

Student::Student() {
}

void Student::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Student::addGrade(int grade) {
    this->grades.push_back(grade);
}

int Student::getBestGrade() {
    return min(this->grades);
}

double Student::getAverageGrade() {
    return average(this->grades);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Student a;
    a.setName("John");
    a.addGrade(15);
    a.addGrade(13);
    a.addGrade(20);
    cout << a.getAverageGrade() << endl;
    cout << a.getBestGrade() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

multiple definition of min(...)
multiple definition of average(...)

It seems I am including "global.h" multiple times. But I don't know where. Indeed, I use `include "Student.h"` two times. But I think the class won't work if I don't to it like this.

Please, help me find out how to include a global library inside a class.

Thanks

**##############################**

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to [WhiteViking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186681/2280418), I have now a solution.

The global.h must have a global.cpp.

**global.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

int min(vector<int> v);
double average(vector<int> v);

#endif  /* GLOBAL_H */
```

**global.cpp**

```
#include "global.h"

int min(vector<int> v) {
    int min = -99999999;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] > min) min = v[i];
    }
    return min;
}

double average(vector<int> v) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        sum += v[i];
    }
    return (double)sum / v.size();
}
```

Comment: Please, post a complete example, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: Why the downvotes? :(

Comment: Did you enclose your header code within include guards to prevent recursive inclusion?

Comment: @skypjack ... I already edited and posted a full example. Please stop downvoting, guys. I think this is a valid question.

Comment: @dspfnder ... Yes, I did. Please, check out the edit with the full example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question does not show this in detail, but it seems you are *defining* `funcX` and `funcY` in `global.h` instead of just *declaring* them.

The preprocessor will replace all `#include` statements with the verbatim contents of those include files. This happens recursively. So after preprocessing, the compiler sees a "A.cpp" that includes the contents of `global.h` with the full definitions of `funcX` and `funcY`. (`global.h` was included indirectly via `A.h`. ) The same thing happens for `Main.cpp`.

After compilation, the object files for `A.cpp` as well as for `Main.cpp` will contain the compiled definitions of `funcX` and `funcY`. The error then happens when these object files are linked together in order to build the final executable. The linker will see multiple definitions of these functions and will error out. (It doesn't know/check/care if these definitions are actually identical.)

The solution is to only *declare* these functions in `global.h` and put their *definition* in a separate `.cpp` file, say `global.cpp`. For example:

In `global.h`:

```
// declarations only here
int funcX(int x);
int funcY(int x);
```

In `global.cpp`:

```
int funcX(int x)
{
    return 2 * x;
}

int funcY(int x)
{
    return x + 42;
}
```

In short: you were violating the so-called One Definition Rule (ODR).

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. You solved my issue even without seeing the full example that I just posted. You are the best. :) PS: If you downvoted, please reconsider, since I posted a full example.

Comment: I did not down vote. Maybe some people did because the essence of the problem (contents of `global.h`) was actually missing in your question? But it's sometimes hard to know what code fragments are relevant and which ones aren't if you don't know the answer yet, and there's some pressure not to post complete programs either... :-) Maybe some people find the question title is unclear? Anyway, don't be put off by a couple of downvotes.

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot. Your help has been precious. :)